# Windows Mobile application formatting messed up on Mobile 6 device

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

I have a Windows Mobile application that was written in Visual Studio 2005 and uses the .NET 2.0 compact framework.  This application, when installed on windows Mobile 5 or 6 devices looks the same.  However, since I have upgraded to Visual Studio 2008, the application looks fine on Windows Mobile 5 devices, but on 6 devices the interface is messed up.  Graphics and buttons are tiny, but text is ok.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Sean M. Severson

Answer (score 0):

It sounds kind of odd, but it maybe have something to do with this two properties:

```
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(192F, 192F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
```